# Facebook Slider as we have seen in Android in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I am working on an application in which I am in a need to implement Android Facebook like slider in BB for O.S version 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0.

I have search but didn't got anything useful. Can anyone suggest me the right way to implement this.?

[image]

Comment: When you say "*slider*", do you mean the **menu** that is revealed by sliding the main screen to the side; which is also connected to the button at the top left, with three horizontal lines?

Comment: yeah,... exactly the same. I have implemented this in Android, easily available.... but looking for this kind of control panel in BB 5.0 and above

Comment: There is nothing that will provide similar functionality drectly, you will have to code it, and it is not trivial.  But why?  If you want a menu on the BB, you press the menu button!  If you really must have this, then what are the key characteristics you need to have?  The slide?  The fact that it has the previous screen partially visible?  The positioning (all the way down the left hand side)?  And do you want this to happen when you press the menu button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*its just a logic. you have to customize its in your way*

```java
boolean val=false;

public MyScreen()
{       

    final ButtonField l=new ButtonField("menu");


    final HorizontalFieldManager hfm_main=new HorizontalFieldManager();

    final VerticalFieldManager vfm_l=new VerticalFieldManager(){
         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(280, maxHeight);
                setExtent(280, maxHeight);
            }
         protected void paint(Graphics g){
                g.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                // Clears the entire graphic area to the current background
                g.clear();
                super.paint(g);
            }
    };
    final VerticalFieldManager vfm_r=new VerticalFieldManager(){
         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
             super.sublayout(maxWidth+300, maxHeight);
             setExtent(maxWidth, maxHeight);
         }
         protected void paint(Graphics g){
             g.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
             // Clears the entire graphic area to the current background
             g.clear();
             super.paint(g);
         }
    };

    vfm_l.add(new LabelField("sliding pannel"));

    vfm_r.add(l);
    vfm_r.add(new LabelField("main view"));

    hfm_main.add(vfm_r);

    add(hfm_main);

 FieldChangeListener listener=new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            if(field==l){
                if(!val){
                    val=true;
                    hfm_main.deleteAll();
                    hfm_main.add(vfm_l);
                    hfm_main.add(vfm_r);
                    hfm_main.invalidate();

            }else{
                val=false;
                hfm_main.deleteAll();
                hfm_main.add(vfm_r);
                hfm_main.invalidate();

            }
            }
        }
    };
    l.setChangeListener(listener);

}
```

Refer [to this post](http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2013/09/creating-facebook-like-slider-menu-in.html)

Comment: Just for the record, the "hfm_main.invalidate();" statements are not needed.